# How to share one Dockerfile for multiple version of my project?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'd like to have one image for each version of my project. But how can I share one dockerfile for all these versions. The only difference is the version number. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a parameter to the docker build call.

E.g., consider the following `Dockerfile` (example for a Node.js project, but the same principals could apply to any type of application):

```
FROM node:10-alpine

# Install 3rd parties required for your application

# Define an argument for the project version
ARG PROJVER

# Use this argument when installing the project
RUN npm install myproject@{PROJVER}
```

Once you have a `Dockerfile` like this, you can build it for a certain version of your project, and of course push it to your registry with that tag:

```
$ export PROJVER=123
$ docker build --build-arg PROJCET_VERSION=${PROJVER} -t myproject:${PROJVER}
$ docker push myregistry:5000/myproject:${PROJVER}
```

Comment: Could this argument be used in FROM statement ? e.g. FROM node:@{VERSION}

Comment: @zjffdu yes indeed, you just have to move the line that defines it (`ARF PROJVER`) above the `FROM` line